# Programmatically close TabItem in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

How the hell do you programmatically close a TabItem in a Windows 8 WPF Desktop TabControl?

There are no options in Intellisense, and the only things that appear in search results are custom implementations of either the TabControl or the TabItem.

Why can't we just do something like `tabControl.SelectedItem.Close();`?

Comment: What do you mean close?

Comment: @ryadavilli Close as in "Selected TabItem not visible anymore - does not exist."

Comment: TabItems don't get "closed" only moved behind the other TabItems when another TabItem in the TabControl is selected.

Comment: There's no option to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that closing is the same as removing TabItem from TabControl

**Edit:**
For Ex:

```
tabControl1.Items.RemoveAt(tabControl1.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: Yeah, well there's no remove option, no close option, no dispose option. Nothing to get rid of any tabitem

Comment: That's really strange, @David, I was just in Intellisense and was looking for a `Remove` method, but couldn't find one. I just ran the code above and it works, but the RemoveAt still doesn't appear in intellisense, which is what led me to believe they got rid of it :/

Comment: Did you look at "Items" property or tabcontrol itself?

Comment: Items property. I originally looked in `tabs.SelectedItem.` but then had a look at `tabs.Items.` and it wasn't in either. Sometimes my intellisense stops appearing so maybe a fresh install of VS?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot close it. `TabItem` is not closeable. You can just hide it:

```
tabControl.SelectedItem.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
```

Comment: :-/ But this does not make much sense. Let's say that the user opens a tab, adds content to it, then opens a new tab. Then then save changes to tab 1, and "Collapses" it - it's still there. And then at a later time (maybe 5 minutes later), then open the same file into a new tab, now there are 2 tabs holding the same content; 1 tab that cannot be seen, and another that can be. Now, I could just make the original tab visible again, but that's where things can get a little difficult, depending on the scenario. Why the hell would they do something like this?

Comment: I got one use case, in this example it is a chat, where the child now collapses itself, the trick to avoid duplicates are upon opening them, instead just check for existing "chats" and make them visible again, I did that already, so for me it made sense to just add a "hide feature"